# How to avoid GC overhead in Android when using media like Images?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, universal-image-loader

I am creating Image apps which has over 4k images. I dont load images as required rather load when required however if user visits different parts of app which links to different images my app becomes slow and waits for GC to run which makes it bad user experience.

I saw logcat with following messages:

10-08 14:21:26.249: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1677K, 13% free 14097K/16124K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
10-08 14:21:26.749: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1711K, 13% free 14092K/16124K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
10-08 14:21:27.610: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1694K, 13% free 14103K/16124K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
10-08 14:21:29.592: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1729K, 13% free 14081K/16124K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
10-08 14:21:30.874: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1675K, 13% free 14102K/16124K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
10-08 14:21:32.435: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1735K, 13% free 14075K/16124K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
10-08 14:21:34.017: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1629K, 13% free 14145K/16124K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
10-08 14:21:35.098: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1774K, 13% free 14093K/16124K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
10-08 14:21:36.290: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1703K, 13% free 14094K/16124K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
10-08 14:21:37.991: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1722K, 13% free 14077K/16124K, paused 27ms, total 28ms
10-08 14:21:39.213: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1693K, 13% free 14083K/16124K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
10-08 14:21:41.175: D/dalvikvm(31547): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1696K, 13% free 14088K/16124K, paused 28ms, total 28ms

I tried to improve/optimize my code by doing following changes:

1. Everytime I load app I clear my cached images.
2. Implemented ViewHolder pattern for ListViews.
3. Used  android:largeHeap="true" attribute in Manifest at Application tag level.
4. Made classes which are used frequently to do some operations singleton.

But still not able to achieve performance i need.

I used Universal Image Loader Library which has cache mechanism but still its runs GC.

How to avoid GC or what are other optimization techniques.

Comment: "I dont load images as required rather load when required" ?

Comment: Basically I have few categories and for each categories i load only three images at start and then click of each category i load all other images.. But its takes time to load images